# Review of a generic request handler class (RestSharp)

Tags: c#, generics

I wrote a class that uses RestSharp to access Rest and HTTP API web services. I tested it and it works however I was wondering if any changes could be made to it to make it better.

```
public class RequestHandler
{
    //Client to translate Rest Request intot HTTP request and process the result.
    private RestClient client;

    //this property stores the base URL
    const string baseUrl = "";

    //stores the account id and secret key if they will be needed for any authentication processes.
    readonly string account_id;
    readonly string secretKey;

    //this property stores the API key
    readonly string accessKey = "";

    //This constructor contains the account id and secret key that will be used for authorization when connecting to the API
    public RequestHandler(string account_id,string secretKey)
    {
        client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
        this.account_id = account_id;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
    }

    //The default constructor 
    public RequestHandler()
    {
        client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
    }

    public void Execute<T>(int id,Action<T> Success, Action<string> Failure) where T:new()
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddParameter("id",id,ParameterType.GetOrPost);

        client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request,(response) =>
        {
            if(response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Error)
            {
                Failure(response.ErrorMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                Success(response.Data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where secret key and account id are used other than assigning them to read only fields in the class.

Comment: I would probably consider at least chaining your constructors so only one of them will actually do the work.  In this case I would probably make your parameterless constructor call the other i.e. RequestHandler() : this(string.Empty, string.Empty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depend on the `IRestClient` interface rather than the `RestClient` implementation and make the field `readonly` as it is only set via the constructor:

```
private readonly IRestClient client;
```

Invert your dependancy on `RestClient`, if you are not using an IOC container, at least implement poor mans injection so that the class is testable (e.g. you can supply a mock `IRestClient` to test `RestHandler`.

```
public RequestHandler() // If you are using an IOC container, remove the default constructor.
    : this(new RestClient(baseUrl))
{
}

public RequestHandler(IRestClient restClient)
{
    this.client = restClient;
}
```

As Ron mentioned above, you don't appear to be using secret key and account id so either remove them if they are not needed or use them.

Making the base url a constant inside the class makes it difficult to re-use, I would move that into the application configuration.

If you do need `account_id`, remove the underscore and camel case it `accountId` to adhere to  the standard naming conventions.

Adding a property for the `DataFormat` will make the class more re-usable if you want to call a web service which doesn't support Json:

```
public DataFormat DataFormat { get; set; }

// Default to Json in the constructor
this.client = restClient
this.DataForma = DataFormat.Json;
```

`ExecuteAsync` returns a `RestRequestAsyncHandle` which allows the request to be aborted, it might be worth looking at whether you need the ability to abort requests or not. You could update your `Execute` to return the wait handle.

The error checking here doesn't account for any of the other reasons for failure such as a timeout or abort.

```
if (response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Error)
```

Update it to something like this:

```
switch (response.ResponseStatus)
{
    ResponseStatus.Completed:
        Success(response.Data);
        break;

    ResponseStatus.Error:
    ResponseStatus.TimedOut:
        Failure(response.ErrorMessage);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Should we also use IRestRequest?